# Dynamically change text size on any screen, like iBook app where small A and Large A buttons are used to change text size at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic

To change text size Dynamically on any screen just like iBook app where small A and Large A are used to change text size at run time. Please help with idea or sample code in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides the full source code of TextEdit as sample code complete with Xcode project. Read that to discover how Apple themselves alter text attributes. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking for an example similar to iBook on iPhone. It should have a slider or "decrease" and "increase" buttons to change the size of text on any screen at run time.

Comment: The TextEdit sample will show you how to change the text itself, your buttons/slider wish is the UI you use to invoke the change. Changing the UI doesn't change what you need to do to change the text itself; study TextEdit to learn the technique, invoke it from your desired UI.

Comment: They are using NSFontManager's modifyFont: to do the magic of changing font. Also they are doing same size for all the text.

Comment: @iking - TextEdit might be doing the same size, but you can do different sizes e.g. a percentage of the current size for each text run. TextEdit also supports zoom in/out where the text itself is not changed just the display factor. Take your pick of which approach suits your application (they produce very different results).

Comment: Can you please suggest any example or sample code implemented for iOS. I am not sure if implementation of TextEdit can be used for iOS. Thanks.

Comment: @iking - Sorry I don't know of an iOS sample. However while Cocoa and CocoaTouch are different there parallels between them so you should be able to use the TextEdit ideas as a starting point for altering the display factor. If you get stuck ask a new question showing the code you've developed and why it isn't working; someone will probably help you at that point.